# Javascript Turn string into array

Tags: javascript, string

I want to turn this into an array

```
"["65747add-afd2-45b5-92e0-150bbe40e6d9", "9c247ea5-6b81-4f47-a50c-42367dedd50b", "c1555363-aca9-4e04-8844-e0180397c72e"]"
```

I am getting it from the page like this:

```
$('#layout-uuids').text()
```

Is there away to just get it as an array or do I need to turn the string into an array somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That string *looks* like [JSON](http://www.json.org/). If it is indeed JSON, all you need is [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var someArray = JSON.parse($('#layout-uuids').text());
```